# Select SFTP connection data for WinSCP .NET assembly from CSV file based on user input

Tags: powershell, csv, sftp, winscp

I have this PowerShell code.
Works good. But when I add more lines to `db.csv`, it doesn't work and return error code:

```
Exception calling "Open" with "1" argument(s): "Connection has been unexpectedly closed. Server sent command exit status 0.
Authentication log (see session log for details):
Using username "username".
Authentication failed."
At C:\Users\me\Desktop\testeScript\CollectLog.ps1:41 char:5
+ $session.Open($sessionOptions)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : SessionRemoteException
```

When I have for example only two lines in `db.csv` the script works very well

```
HostName,IP
name1,10.10.1.1
name2,10.10.1.2
```

I try with 19 hostname and Ip addr line in CSV doc and works, but when I add only 1 more stopping works.

19 works
20+ doesn't work..

Any idea? (Thank you and sorry for my english)

```
Add-Type -Path "WinSCPnet.dll"
 
$Name = @()
$ip = @()
 
Import-Csv db.csv |`
    ForEach-Object {
        $Name += $_.HostName
        $ip += $_.IP
    }
 
$inputID = Read-Host -Prompt "Type ID"
 
if ($Name -contains $inputID)
    {
    $Where = [array]::IndexOf($Name, $inputID)
    Write-Host "IP: " $ip[$Where]
    }
 
# Set up session options
$sessionOptions = New-Object WinSCP.SessionOptions -Property @{
    Protocol = [WinSCP.Protocol]::Sftp
    HostName = "$ip"
    UserName = "username"
    Password = "password"
    GiveUpSecurityAndAcceptAnySshHostKey = "true"
}
 
$session = New-Object WinSCP.Session
 
try
{
    # Connect
    $session.Open($sessionOptions)
 
    # Transfer files
    $session.GetFiles("/C:/Program Files/Common Files/logs/Device.log", "E:\loguri\Log\Arhive\*").Check()
}
finally
{
    $session.Dispose()
}
 
Compress-Archive -Path "E:\loguri\Log\Arhive\Device.log" -DestinationPath "E:\loguri\Log\Arhive\$inputID.zip" -Update
Remove-Item -Path "E:\loguri\Log\Arhive\Device.log" -Force
```

Comment: Why are you splitting the data from the csv into two separate arrays? Add a `catch{}` block between the `try{..}  finally{..}` to figure out the problem `$_.Exception.Message`

Comment: Thank you for response , can you show me exactly your ideea on script? (I'm really newbie, now I try to learn) Thank you in advance :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as Theo says you have no need to separate out your CSV into two arrays as you have.  Import it like this

```
$db = import-csv 'db.csv'
```

You can access each row as `$db[0]`, `$db[1]` and each column from your CSV will be a property, e.g. `$db[0].Hostname` and `$db[0].IP`

After you have read in your input you just need to select the entry from the array `$db`.  Perhaps like this.  However neither your code nor mine covers the case where is no match!

```
$entry = $db -match $inputID
```

Then your session will be defined like this

```
$sessionOptions = New-Object WinSCP.SessionOptions -Property @{
    Protocol = [WinSCP.Protocol]::Scp
    HostName = $entry.ip
    UserName = "username"
    Password = "password"
    GiveUpSecurityAndAcceptAnySshHostKey = "true"
}
```

With all that said, given the error message that you have it would appear that the combination of username/password and ip are not valid.

```
Add-Type -Path "WinSCPnet.dll"
 
$db = import-csv 'db.csv'
 
$inputID = Read-Host -Prompt "Type ID"
 
$entry = $db -match $inputID
 
# Set up session options
$sessionOptions = New-Object WinSCP.SessionOptions -Property @{
    Protocol = [WinSCP.Protocol]::Sftp
    HostName = $entry.IP
    UserName = "username"
    Password = "password"
    GiveUpSecurityAndAcceptAnySshHostKey = "true"
}
 
$session = New-Object WinSCP.Session
 
try {
    # Connect
    $session.Open($sessionOptions)
 
    # Transfer files
    $session.GetFiles("/C:/Program Files/Common Files/logs/Device.log", "E:\loguri\Log\Arhive\*").Check()
}
finally {
    $session.Dispose()
}

if (Test-Path "E:\loguri\Log\Arhive\Device.log") {
  Compress-Archive -Path "E:\loguri\Log\Arhive\Device.log" -DestinationPath "E:\loguri\Log\Arhive\$inputID.zip" -Update
  Remove-Item -Path "E:\loguri\Log\Arhive\Device.log" -Force
}
```

Comment: I separete CSV because I need to entry one ID after that capture correspondend. (?)

So, per eg: I have db.csv (format HostName,IP) line 1 : Name,10.10.10.10 after that line 2 Name2,10.10.10.11 and more that hundreds.

Comment: That's ok, your CSV can have hundreds of lines:

    Hostname,IP
    host1,192.168.1.1
    host2,192.168.1.2
    host3,192.168.1.3
    host4,192.168.1.4
    host5,192.168.1.5
    host6,192.168.1.6
    host7,192.168.1.7
    host8,192.168.1.8
    host9,192.168.1.9
    host10,192.168.1.10
    ...
    hostn,a.b.c.d

You would import it in the same way.  $mydb = inport-csv db.csv

Comment: You could also loop through your database to collect all the logs from all the machines automatically without needing to specify the name.  For example: `$db = import-csv 'db.csv' ; foreach ($host in $db) { $sessionsOptions ..... HostName = $host.ip .... etc }`

Comment: And if each host has a different username and password you could extend it further with your CSV containing additional columns for username and password then your `$sessionsOptions`could reflect that with `Username = $host.username` and `Password = $host.password`

Comment: Host have same username and same password. Can you edit my script ? I really don't know exactly how can I make that :| .

Comment: I try to change my script before you sent and with my edit doesn't work, now with your script work well. (find text and correspondend) I think I didn't implement corectly. Thank you very much Mark (y) for helping me. Now this works good, but the same Error for connectiong :

Comment: ```Exception calling "Open" with "1" argument(s): "Connection has been 
unexpectedly closed. Server sent command exit status 0.
Authentication log (see session log for details):
Using username "username".
Access denied.
Authentication failed."
At C:\Users\me\Desktop\testScriptLog\CollectLog.ps1:24 
char:5
+     $session.Open($sessionOptions)
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SessionRemoteException
```